# Issue while generating unique alphabets in PHP

Tags: php, random

Am trying to generate a unique value in PHP where the first and last letters should be J and 1 respectively while the middle characters should be a series of aplhabetical letters and the whole value should be 7 in total eg **JWERYH1** Please assist?

```
$let = chr(rand(65, 90));

$all = 'J' . $let . '1';

dd($all);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
$chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
$res = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $res .= $chars[mt_rand(0, strlen($chars)-1)];
}

echo 'J'.$res.'1';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$let = "";
for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
    $let .= chr(rand(65, 90));
}
$all = 'J' . $let . '1';
```

1. You prepare an empty var `$let`
2. You need a 7 lenght var with 2 fixed char (J and 1) so you need `$let` to be 5 length : you need to loop 5 times and get 5 randoms chars
3. Now you get your 7 lenght string with `J` + `$let` + `1`

Eg. of result after 5 attempts :

```
JJGBIP1
JRPYGO1
JBONBW1
JCLVSY1
JRDHGI1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of all the letters with range().
Then shuffle it and extract the first five letters and use implode to make them a string.

```
$letters = range("A", "Z");

shuffle($letters);

$all = 'J' . implode("",array_slice($letters,0,5)) . '1';
echo $all;
```

https://3v4l.org/KuZ2H

This means you only do one "random" function which is the shuffle and no looping in PHP.